# shared hosting explicit site on same IP

Tags: seo, google, web-hosting, shared-hosting

IM doing shared hosting via godaddy.

I have just done a check and found that there are some "explicit" aka spammy porn sites hosted on the same IP address as my website, **can this affect my rankings?**

Private Hosting is very expensive but will it be beneficial for me to make the move?

Ideally I would like to keep things as it is but this explicit sites residing on the same host as my well maintained reputable site is worrying me...

Comment: _Aside:_ You don't necessarily need "Private Hosting" in order to avoid prOn sites on the same IP address. A reputable host with an appropriate Terms of Service could be sufficient.

Comment: The answer is yes. You can be penalized. Though generally, it is more difficult than it once was. I remind users who have been here for a while that we had a period where sites were being routinely severely penalized for moving some resources to a CDN where the IP address was used for bad things. The penalty often came immediately in just hours or a day and took a while to remove. The bad neighborhood effect is very real, however, Google has become far less severe of late. It takes a fair amount of bad content/sites to make this effect happen. Cheers!!